# ISurface.GetElevation extremely slow compared to GlobalMapper

Tags: arcobjects, raster, c#, elevation

I'm using ISurface.GetElevation on a Raster to get the elevation for a specific lat/lon.

I have to do this for a huge set of datapoints.

Currently i'm testing with a dataset of 10.000 items which takes Esri over 30 seconds but is executed by GlobalMapper within half a second.

Is there any other way to quickly retrieve the elevation (bi. interpolated if needed) using Esri ArcObjects function ?

I'm working in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If it is one raster, I usually use [IIdentify2:Identify method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Identify_Method/00120000062v000000/), to get the cell value, and get the height.  ISurface.GetElevation gives you the interpolated value, and if your cell size is large, then there might be a large difference between the two. Otherwise, It usually is good enough.